# Fast greedy on graph objects

Tags: r, igraph

So I have read in my network data in csv file and turn it into graph object by doing the following

```
g = read.csv"somefile.csv", header = FALSE)
G = graph.data.frame(g,directed=FALSE)
fc = cluster_fast_greedy(G)

Error in cluster_fast_greedy(G) : 
At fast_community.c:639 : fast-greedy community finding works only on graphs 
without multiple edges, Invalid value
```

Very interesting is, I tried loading the graphml version directly and can run the `fast greedy` function with no error.

My question is if I am restricted to csv file only, how can I run the fast_greedy function on it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the error message says,

> fast-greedy community finding works only on graphs without multiple edges

But you can remove the multiple edges using the `simplify` function.
Here is an example. First, I create a graph with multiple edges - on which 
`fastgreedy.community` fails.  But after simplify, it works.

```
set.seed(1234)
g = erdos.renyi.game(12, 0.3)
g = add_edges(g, c(1,5, 7,10))
fastgreedy.community(g)
Error in .Call("R_igraph_community_fastgreedy", graph, as.logical(merges),  : 
  At fast_community.c:553 : fast-greedy community finding works 
  only on graphs without multiple edges, Invalid value

g = simplify(g)
fastgreedy.community(g)
IGRAPH clustering fast greedy, groups: 2, mod: 0.26
+ groups:
  $`1`
  [1]  1  3  4  5  9 10 11

  $`2`
  [1]  2  6  7  8 12
```

Comment: That solves the problem. But why can I run `fast_greedy` directly on the unmodified graphml data where the csv version failed.

Comment: Without having your data, it is pretty hard to diagnose. Can you make a small example so that you can add the data to your question?